# Google Analytics Restrict view to show specific campaign

Tags: google-analytics

Hi I wanted to define a custom view in google analytics and restrict that view to only show data related to a specific campaign and nothing more, is it possible?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new ***View*** with an *include* filter allowing only the specific campaign name:

[image]